# What just happened to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, downtime

Stack Overflow was down for a long time here, probably about an hour.

What was the cause?

Comment: https://twitter.com/StackStatus

Comment: @Pëkka - Doesn't explain much. DOS attack?

Comment: EVERYBODY PANIC

Comment: @MartinSmith Yup, [DDOS](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/435142863874449408)

Comment: I wonder if this map is depicting this attack: http://www.digitalattackmap.com/

Comment: Wow.... A few minutes without SO made me clear up my desk and listen to some music I wanted long ago... I think I am over the line, I just don't know which line that is...

Comment: I wonder who would launch a DDOS on SE? Somebody who got banned and wanted revenge? :P

Comment: @Mystical: Whoever did it, I'm sure at one point in their development of the DDOS tool they got advice from SE. (Assuming the people who launched it developed the tool, which is probably unlikely...)

Comment: @Mysticial well, maybe someone's "print a triangle of stars in Java" homework question might have been downvoted beyond recognition in the first 3 seconds...

Comment: @ppeterka That might have been my fault for CV-ing... :P

Comment: Some SE sites are still down.

Comment: @Kaveh [english.se] is one.

Comment: @Kaveh [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) is another one still down

Comment: And also Maths SE

Comment: All dns records for SE sites have to be updated, that takes a while

Comment: @Bleeding, [math.se] also seems down.

Comment: There are still a lot of sites down. This will take some time indeed.

Comment: @Kaveh So is [cstheory.se]. Gosh some resting time for the mods there :p

Comment: @Bleeding, yes. :)

Comment: @Kaveh Graphic design is still down

Comment: Codegolf down, SO in portuguese down. gamedev down. But area 51 and software recommendations are up.

Comment: We are effectively creating a list of down SE sites here.

Comment: Looks like @rene is correct. Added `198.252.206.140 dba.stackexchange.com` to my hosts file and can now access that site.

Comment: @Kaveh [Photography](http://photo.stackexchange.com) is also affected.

Comment: May be this has something got to do with Anonymous Group, of which I am sure. They are actually good to us, but may be I made them angry in some last 3 hours.

Comment: It's not the time to panic...... Now it's time to panic.

Comment: So *that's* why I can't access Stack Apps...

Comment: If you can access any site with any SE IP address, then I'm curious why there is only one DNS entry for each of the sites

Comment: Anime and manga SE is up... But that's the only one that I can access...

Comment: Travel and cooking are down

Comment: Indian Baba is attacking with black magic.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The StackStatus twitter account says [this](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/435130357546254336):

> Our network provider is experiencing a bit of increased traffic.  We and they are investigating.

[Update](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/435142863874449408):

> We have partially mitigated a DDoS attack against our network. We are continuing to watch traffic.

Answer (score 65):

[Someone listened to Nick, it seems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129814/what-should-be-done-about-a-user-who-makes-a-threat/129828#129828)

[image]

Oops.

Comment: @michaelb958 [status-completed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ltRXb.png)

Comment: Punch Punch Punch