# Subdomains of StackExchange.com still down

Tags: support, status-completed

After being DDOSed (cf. [What just happened to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221418/)) StackOverflow works again and Meta.SO obviously, as well. I also noticed, that superuser.com works. But all subdomains of stackexchange.com are still down (I actually did test only some of them).

Are there known reasons? Can someone tell something about a time span, how long this will last?

IS the actual problem now, that perhaps thousands of users continiously are pinging their favorite SE site?

Comment: Well, more and more SE sites are going back up, but I have no clue how long it will be for all of them to go back up

Comment: @GeoffDalgas I see you marked this [meta-tag:status-completed], but please see http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1956.

Comment: Thanks for the notification @msh210 - I have pushed a change for this domain.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

We have performed a DNS change to mitigate a DDOS attack.  Hopefully your favorite Stack Exchange site will be coming back to life here in a bit.  We are monitoring the situation closely.

Comment: Remark: Users should also flush the DNS cache on their local machines.

Answer (score 20):

This is funny ([in Ask Ubuntu only 10kers](https://askubuntu.com/q/421850/169736)):

[image]

Comment: Could be real, or could just be some lozer who thinks they're being funny.  I'm leaning towards the latter.

Comment: @RobertHarvey could be taking credit for someones work D:.

Comment: @Speravir: It's almost certainly deleted by now.

Comment: @RobertHarvey They've been threatening this for a while now..

Comment: So I guess I wasn't wrong when I said this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221418/what-just-happened-to-stackoverflow#comment719044_221418

Comment: @Mysticial Nope.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal: Already deleted. Screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BzpBN.png

Comment: LOL! That's so stupid.

Answer (score 12):

From my side it looks like the Stack Exchange Network is doing a failover which impacts the IP adresses for the servers. For all domains the DNS records has to be updated and then those updates need to propagate to all DNS servers and finally your own box.

The updating takes time. Maybe because a human has to enter the new IP addresses in some management console at an ISP hosting the DNS.

Comment: Thanks, René. It’s mean, that an admin answered, too. ;-)

Comment: That is the only truth...I upvoted Geoff his answer