# Stack Overflow em Português offline?

Tags: support, offline, portuguese-stackoverflow

Stack Overflow in Portuguese is offline, and its meta as well. Other Stack Exchange sites appear to be normal. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: There's an ongoing DDOS attack going on, see here; [What just happened to StackOverflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221418/what-just-happened-to-stackoverflow)

Comment: Thanks @RichardTingle. I guess it's probably the same issue, although SO and MSO are up now.

Comment: Sites seem to be coming back one by one; [Subdomains of StackExchange.com still down](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/221432/subdomains-of-stackexchange-com-still-down)